# Save recorded video from AVFoundation

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am not able to save the recorder video from AVFoundation... In didfinishcapture I check if file exists in the temporary folder, code always returns NO.

Also, this warning is printed when i stop the recording:
 "cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2 "This movie could not be played." UserInfo=0x1c5696c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=This movie could not be played.}"

```
#define OP_PATH [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"movie" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"]]


        - (IBAction) startSession:(id)sender
        {
            if(! self.captureSession)
            {
                //Session
                self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

                //self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;


                //Layer of own view
                CALayer *viewLayer = self.captureView.layer;


                //AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
                AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *avCaptureLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession];

                avCaptureLayer.frame = self.captureView.bounds;

                [self.captureView.layer addSublayer:avCaptureLayer];


                //AVCaptureDevice
                AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

                NSError *err = nil;


                //Output - Image
                self.stillImgOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];

                [self.stillImgOutput setOutputSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                                   AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey,

                                                   nil]];

                [self.captureSession addOutput:self.stillImgOutput];


                //Output - Video
                self.movieOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

        //        NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey;
        //        
        //        NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];
        //        
        //        NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];

                if([self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.movieOutput])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Movie out put added");

                    [self.captureSession addOutput:self.movieOutput];
                }

                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Cannot add movie out put");
                }



                //Input
                AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&err];

                if(! input)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error no camera");

                    return;
                }

                if([self.captureSession canAddInput:input])
                {
                    [self.captureSession addInput:input];
                }

                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Cannot add input. Check Output Settings");
                }
            }

            if(! [self.captureSession isRunning])
            {
                [self.captureSession startRunning];
            }

            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Session already running");
            }
        }


    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Did stop recording to - %@ \n Any error ? - %@", outputFileURL, [error description]);

        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[outputFileURL absoluteString]])
        {
            NSLog(@"YES file exists");
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"NO File does not exist");
        }

        if(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum([outputFileURL absoluteString]))
        {
            NSLog(@"YES file is compatible to be saved in Album");

            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([outputFileURL absoluteString], self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"NO File is not compatible");
        }
    }


    - (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
    {
        if(! error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Video Saved to Album");
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Video not saved to Album - %@", [error description]);
        }

        NSError *er;

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:OP_PATH error:&er];

        if(! er)
        {
            NSLog(@"Temporary file deleted");
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Temporary file not deleted - %@", [er description]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But still it wont affect the save code ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the following piece of code. See below

```
//Use timestamp to get new movie name everytime you capture
NSString *timeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

NSString *movieOutputUrl =[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov",timeStamp]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:movieOutputUrl];
[self.movieOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:url recordingDelegate:self];
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: naaaa. still the same ERROR ! its driving me crazy !

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutputdidFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundRecordingID = [self backgroundRecordingID];
    [self setBackgroundRecordingID:UIBackgroundTaskInvalid];

    [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputFileURL error:nil];

        if (backgroundRecordingID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundRecordingID];
        }
    }];
}
```

Hope can help.